# use concurrent futures with generator input

Tags: python, concurrency

I am downloading some information from webpages in the form

```
http://example.com?p=10
http://example.com?p=20
...
```

The point is that I don't know how many they are. At some point I will receive an error from the server, or maybe at some point I want to stop the processing since I have enough. I want to run them in parallel.

```
def generator_query(step=10):
   i = 0
   yield "http://example.com?p=%d" % i
   i += step
```

```
def task(url):
    t = request.get(url).text
    if not t:  # after the last one
       return None
    return t
```

I can implement it with consumer/producer pattern with queues, but I am wondering it is possible to have an higher level implementation, for example with the concurrent module.

Non-concurrent example:

```
results = []
for url in generator_query():
    results.append(task(url))
```

Comment: are you downloading them in a steaming fashion: one by one with potential delay? Post a context where `generator_query` is invoked

Comment: I want to download several (= number of workers) in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You could use **concurrent**'s **ThreadPoolExecutor**. An example of how to use it is provided [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).
You'll need to break out of the example's for-loop, when you're getting invalid answers from the server (the **except** section) or whenever you feel like you got enough data (you could count valid responses in the **else** section for example).

Answer (score 0):

You could use aiohttp for this purpose:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def coro(step):
    url = 'https://example.com?p={}'.format(step)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, url)
        print(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [coro(i*10) for i in range(10)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

as for the page error, you might have to figure it yourself since I don't know what website you're dealing with. Maybe try...except?

Notice: if your python version is higher than 3.5, it might cause an ssl certificate verification error.

Comment: you are assuming I have maximum 10 steps. I don't know how many I have. I can know it only after having fetched all until I get an error.